# Syntax error in printf command in c programming

Tags: c, syntax, printf, scanf

Just for context, I am a complete beginner at programming and learning C is my first experience at coding.

I do not know why I am receiving error in line 12 and line 15 of my program. I probably think it is some syntax error which I do not know about. Could someone point it out to me?

The code which I used is as follows:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float maths, eng, phy, chem, pe;

    printf("\nEnter maths marks:");
    scanf("%f",&maths);

    printf("\nEnter eng marks:");
    scanf("%f",&eng);

    printf("\nEnter phy marks:");
    scanf("%f",&phy);

    printf("\nEnter chem marks:");
    scanf("%f",&chem);

    printf("\nEnter pe marks:");
    scanf("%f",&pe);
}
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83CH3.png)

Comment: Please post code as text, and post the full error message.

Comment: Have you tried clicking the tab that says `PROBLEMS (2)`? Aside: the [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) specifier for `float` is `%f`, not `%d`. Other than that, please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Oka, yes I tried doing that but it just asked to place semicolons [9,5] and [11,5], which didn't make sense at all.                                                                                                           P.S I'm extremely sorry if I have not framed my question right. I'll definitely learn more about it the next time :)

Comment: In its current state, your program compiles and no error is being shown for the 2 `printf`s (though there's a `scanf` typo). Have you actually tried compiling the program to see if the compiler itself gives errors? And can you quote exactly what the problems in the problems tab say?

Comment: It's compiling now and running as intended but the 2 errors (in image attached) are still there. I just don't know how they are affecting my program

Comment: In case you are using Visual Studio, there's a high chance that you are getting the version which hasn't been updated since year 1990 and therefore doesn't support implicit `return 0;` at the end of main(). Avoid such problems by not using Visual Studio or just use it as IDE and set it to use gcc compiler.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Being at a pretty early stage, I don't know what's a linter. Is it something I need to worry about?

Comment: @MuditSharma "Linter" is slang for static analyser, an external tool giving more extensive warnings than a compiler. And no, it's not something beginners should use or worry about.

Comment: @Lundin How is that possible when I installed Visual studio code just two days back?

Comment: @MuditSharma Because Microsoft only maintain their C++ compiler. Their C compiler is not very C compliant, though the newest versions aren't quite as awful as 2015 or earlier. Anyway, I actually think this is some IDE issue. Maybe you didn't save the file or maybe you are viewing another file than the one being compiled?

Comment: I'd just ignore these red squiggles as long as your program _compiles_ without warnings. It's probably a bug of the IDE.

Comment: @Lundin I had saved the file correctly and it's the same as the one being compiled. I guess you are right about it being an IDE issue. So I'll not waste my as well as yours time on it :)

Comment: @MuditSharma I think on VSCode there's an option to disable error squiggles. If you want to detect actual errors you can at least see them when compiling.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Yes, there is. I didn't disable it though thinking it wouldn't show even genuine errors in the future. But I'll do so now. Thanks

Comment: @Lundin, why are linters "not something beginners should use or worry about"? I think linters are extremely useful for beginners, since they will provide valuable feedback and help you develop good programming patterns instead of bad ones. If you start using them after you wrote 10000 lines of code, they will probably yield so many warnings most users will ignore them.

Comment: @wovano The reason is that you need plenty of experience to use them, so that you can tell what's false positives and what's not. Most static analysers currently on the market are in a poor state with lots of noise. Blindly trusting them, as a beginner would have to do, is the worst you can do.

Comment: @Lundin, I agree that blindly trusting any tool is bad. But if you'd want to learn a language you could research the warnings. I think it also depends on the language used. I write a lot of Python code, and the common analyzers (e.g. pylint) are correct >99% of the time. When writing C code, there's indeed a lot more noise from the static analyzers and it might require expert knowledge to distinguish the false positives from the nasty bugs... So I understand your point, but I would formulate it a bit more conservative: blindly ignoring is just as bad as blindly trusting :-)

Comment: @wovano My advise comes from using some five different analysers over the years and they all ranged from bad to terrible. The most expensive ones were not necessarily the best.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. It was actually a bug as suggested by many people. Disabling and re-enabling error squiggles has solved it completely. Thanks to everyone who helped me out :)

Answer (score -1):

You should specify access specifier `%f` for float datatypes.
So your code should be,

```
scanf("%f",&maths);
```

Comment: That's likely not the cause of the error squiggles on the `printf`. Currently, the question is incomplete as it has code in a picture and doesn't have a MRE so any answer is likely to be incomplete as well.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Could you please elaborate more on that? I tried newCodee's solution but that didn't work.

Comment: @MuditSharma please send the complete code as text

Comment: @MuditSharma what I'm saying is that for us to be able to answer you, you need to send a [mcve] of the program as a code block, *not* as a picture. You should also show what problems are being shown in the "problems" tab and if you get any errors when actually compiling the program. There is an option to edit your question so you can still add this info.

Comment: The code in the question has changed, so this answer doesn't make sens anymore.